# How can I get the variable in the model for the controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

I have a `$send` variable in my model. I want to use it on the controller. But I get an error. How can I call it to the controller?

Model:

```
public function register_user($send)
  {

    if($this->emailVerify()) {
      $send = array(
        'tipo' => 'Error.'
      );
      return true;

    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

Controller:

```
   public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->send;
    }
    public function register()
        {
            $this->load->model('users');
            $this->users->register_user();
            $this->load->view('signup', $this->send);
        }
```

Comment: You can't use this variable but you can use its value. Also, you can collect values into array and return this array back to the controller and after you can use its indexes with corresponded values. Choose.

Comment: Quick question: Why would you send an error if  `if($this->emailVerify()){` returns `true`? I think you need the other way round.

Comment: The `emailVerify()` function checks whether an email already exists in the database. If it exists, it sends the error. If not, he will register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a private variable, say `send` in your model and make `getter` and `setter` in your model class in an encapsulated way to get the value in the controller, like below:

**Snippet:**

**Model:**

```
<?php

class Yourmodel extends CI_Model{
    private $send;
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->send = [];
    }

    public function register_user($send){
        if($this->emailVerify()) {
          $this->send = array(
            'tipo' => 'Error.'
          );

          return true;
        } 

        return false;
    }

    public function setSendValue($value){
        $this->send = $value;
    }

    public function getSendValue(){
        return $this->send;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

class Controller extends CI_Controller{
    private $send;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->send = [];
    }

    public function register(){
        $this->load->model('users');
        if($this->users->register_user()){
            $this->send = $this->users->getSendValue();
        }
        $this->load->view('signup', $this->send);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code modal and controller as follows:

1. You need not to declare **$send** in modal definition, as you are not passing any value while calling the same modal function.
2. modal positive return can be array **$send** itself
3. Catch value of modal function

Modal :

```
public function register_user()
  {

    if($this->emailVerify()) {
      $send = array(
        'tipo' => 'Error.'
      );
      return $send;

    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

Controller:

```
       public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->send;
        }
        public function register()
            {
                $this->load->model('users');
                $send = $this->users->register_user();
        //print_r($send); // You will get data here
                $this->load->view('signup', $this->send);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
public function register_user($send = "")
  {

    if($this->emailVerify()) {
      $send = array(
        'tipo' => 'Error.'
      );
      return $send;

    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->send;
    }
    public function register()
        {
            $this->load->model('users');
            $sendRes = $this->users->register_user(); //now you can use this $send response variable
            $this->load->view('signup', $this->send);
        }
```